# Codeigniter Jquery Ajax, Can't access data from controller back to html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

am trying to process data from **htmlform** using jquery ajax to codeigniter but It doesn't return any value.

**This is the jquery codes am using to process data**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chat_create_room").submit(function(){
        var chat_name = $(".chat_name").val();
        $("#response").html('<b>Fetching data...</b>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'site/create_chat_room',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {chat_room_name: chat_name},
            success: function(data){
                $("#response").html(data.chat_room_name);
                $("#submit").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**And this is the codeigniter controller function  am using to grab data from Jquery**

```
public function create_chat_room(){
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

         $data = array(
         'chat_room_name'  => $this->input->post('chat_room_name')
         );
         $chat_room_name =  json_encode($data);
         $table_exists = $this->users->table_exists($chat_room_name);

         if($table_exists){
            echo 'Sorry the table you choose already exist!';
         }else{
            echo "<strong>".$chat_room_name."</strong> has been created!";
         }

       }else{
           $this->load->view('view_site');
       }
```

But if I try this in codeigniter controller function it works fine

```
public function create_chat_room(){

     $data = array(
     'chat_room_name'  => $this->input->post('chat_room_name')
     );

    $chat_room_name= json_encode($data);
     echo $chat_room_name;

}
```

The main thing I want is, to first process the given value (**which is Json object**) from Jquery to Codeigniter Controller and then check weather the given value exists in the database and if the value exist i alert the user with any message

Thank you

Comment: Try changing the datatype to html...

Comment: you are returning html not data. In your other example you echo the json encoded data so therefore get a response

Comment: Yes, if I echo the last example I get a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying different options but finally I got it
, I just had to adjust some few things such as instead of processing json into codeigniter controller I had to just process normal data.

**Jquery code**

```
$("#chat_create_room").submit(function(){
    var chat_name = $(".chat_name");
    $("#response").html('<img src="img/ugchat_loader.GIF"/>');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'site/create_chat_room',
        data : chat_name,
        success : function(res){
            if(res == ""){
            $("#response").html('Nothing returned!');
        }else{
           $("#response").html(res);
        }
        }
    });
    $(".chat_name").val('');
    return false;
```

**After wards grab every thing using Codeigniter controller**

```
public function create_chat_room(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
      sleep(3);
     $chat_room_name = $this->input->post('chat_room_name');
     $table_exists = $this->users->table_exists($chat_room_name);
     if($table_exists){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error</strong> Sorry the chatroom name is already taken!</div>';
     }else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success</strong> Your chatroom has been created</div>';
     }

   }else{
       redirect(base_url()."site");
   }
```

**And the model**
Basically this function check's whether a table is contained in our database
and return true or false;

Afterwards, we evaluate our result and test it in our controller  and then return the data back to our html

```
public function table_exists($table_exists){
    $tables = $this->db->table_exists($table_exists);
    if($tables){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

I hope it helps
**nulldev**